# Postgres - Constraint if attribute in one table match with a key in another [CREATE TABLE]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem I can't solve. I have two tables `Branches` and `Students`. Each student has a program attribute and each Branch is has a name and a program, these are a combined primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE Branches(
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    program TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (name, program),
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Programs(name)
);

CREATE TABLE Students(
    idnr NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    login TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    program TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Programs(name)

);
```

I want to create a new table, `StudentBranches` holding information about what, if any, branch a student is belonging to. This is my code so far:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentBranches(
    student NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    branch TEXT NOT NULL, 
    program TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES Students(idnr),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branches(name,program)
);
```

My question is this, I need to check so the program from Branches foreign key is the same as the program assigned to the student. I can't use any triggers. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique constraint to students with both the number and the program:

```
CREATE TABLE Students (
    idnr NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    login TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    program TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (program) REFERENCES Programs(name),
    UNIQUE (program, idnr)
);
```

This is a little redundant -- after all `idnr` is already unique.  However, it allows you to add a foreign key reference that includes the `program`:

```
CREATE TABLE StudentBranches(
    student NUMERIC(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    branch TEXT NOT NULL, 
    program TEXT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (student) REFERENCES Students(idnr),
    FOREIGN KEY (program, student) REFERENCES Students(program, idnr,),
    FOREIGN KEY (branch, program) REFERENCES Branches(name,program)
);
```